# Find a character index in string in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am SQL person and new to Spark SQL

I need to find the position of character index '-' is in the string if there is then i need to put the fix length of the character otherwise length zero

```
string name = 'john-smith'
```

if  '-' is in character position 4 then 10 otherwise length 0

I have done in SQL Server but now need to do in Spark SQL.

```
select 
case 
when charindex('-', name) = 4 then 10
else 0 
end
```

I tried in Spark SQL but failed to get results.

```
select find_in_set('-',name)
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `instr` function as shown next. `insrt` checks if the second string argument is part of the first one. If so, then it returns its index starting from 1.

```
#first create a temporary view if you don't have one already
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")

#then use instr to check if the name contains the - char
spark.sql("select if(instr(name, '-') = 4, 10, 0) from temp_table")
```

The arguments for the `if` statement are:

- `instr(name, '-') = 4` condition to check
- 10 result for valid condition
- 0 result for false condition

Comment: Perfect all sorted. There is no need to create temp table (may be for me) instr function works perfectly. Thank you @Alexandros.

Comment: Is there a way this could be done in pyspark?